# Get errorlevel in cmd script calling ssh

Tags: ssh, batch, exit-code

`ssh -i private_linux_key user@machine "exit 1" || echo %errorlevel%`

This always prints `0`. How can I get actual error code returned by ssh?

`||` somehow detects that there was an error.

Comment: Well `ssh` exited cleanly, so the return value *is* `0`.

Comment: I understand this. But what is the proper way to get exit code returned from ssh session?

Comment: You could append `;echo $?` to your command, but that won't set the `errorlevel` variable :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, thanks to following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554324/batch-file-errorlevel-issue

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ssh -i private_linux_key user@machine "exit 1" || echo !errorlevel!
```

Or even simplier

```
ssh -i private_linux_key user@machine "exit 1"
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The latter is possible only when there are no more additional script lines after `exit`, of course

To read more about `enabledelayedexpansion` and windows/unix shells differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx